# Running js tests - getting "Cannot use import statement outside of a module"

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocha.js, babeljs

I added the `type: module` but that didn't help.

I am trying to run mocha or jest tests that use `import` and `export` for the source files.

The existing questions about this have specifics that are different from mine and I also find them confusing to follow for someone with my specific situation, especially since I have developed a specific answer with details not relevant to the existing questions, but relevant to other people in my situation.

Comment: Again you haven't supplied enough information in the question to get to the answer you've written. [Self-answered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) still need to meet the basic requirements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per [the Jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started#using-babel), if you make sure `babel-jest` is installed and supply your Babel configuration per [the Babel documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files), in a config file or `package.json` e.g.:

`.babelrc.json`

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/env"
  ]
}
```

Then `babel-jest` will pick it up automatically and you don't need to explicitly pre-build the files to test them. This also means you don't have to set flags on the command line when calling Babel.

---

Note that if you *do* want to explicitly pre-build, I'd recommend:

1. Using a `pre<script>` script rather than having multiple steps in one line; and
2. Re-using the `build` script so you don't have to make changes in two places.

In your case:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "babel src/ --out-dir lib",
  "pretest": "npm run build",
  "test": "jest lib/*.test.js"
}
```

Comment: A small bounty as a thank you for continued help :)

Comment: Additional info about script/ on https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

Answer (score 9):

In the past, you could not use ES modules (i.e. `import`/`export`) in Node without transpiling your code using Babel. However, support for ES modules in Node is now a reality, and both Jest and Mocha have also recently added support for using ES modules natively.

It takes more than just adding `"type": "module"` to your *package.json*, however.

### Steps for using native ES Modules in Jest

1. As already mentioned, add `"type": "module"` to your *package.json*
2. Install either `jest-environment-node` or `jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen` to your development dependencies. For example:

   ```sh
   $ npm i -D jest-environment-node
   ```
3. Update the Jest configuration in *package.json* and add the `testEnvironment` setting.  For example:

   ```
   "jest": {
       "testEnvironment": "jest-environment-jsdom-node"
   }
   ```
4. If you are using a version of Node earlier than 13.2, then you will need to add two additional flags when running Node: `--experimental-modules` and `experimental-vm-modules`. I use `npx` to execute the commands, although it's a little verbose:

   ```sh
   $ npx --node-arg=--experimental-modules --node-arg=--experimental-vm-modules jest
   ```

This will run all your Jest tests using the appropriate Node flags. I'd recommend making this your `test` script in `package.json` if this is the way you go.

Now you should be able to use `import`/`export` without Babel!

One last important point: when using native ES modules in Node, you have to use the entire import path to your local modules, including the file extensions. For example:

```js
import lib from "./my/lib.js"
```

Here is the Node documentation on native ES modules, if you want to read about this in more detail: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/esm.html

I'd also recommend reading through this Github issue for more details on the Jest implementation of native ES modules: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9430

Comment: +400 (my bounty) for a good answer from a new contributor.  Welcome !!!  It gives me joy to spend my reputation points welcoming you.

Comment: In addition, for those who are using a 14.x version of Node, you only need the `--node-arg=--experimental-vm-modules`. `--node-arg=--experimental-modules` is not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a compiler and then use the compiled files when running tests.

Many of the references say to add `type: module` but don't say much more.
To be clear, the basic message:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

is because you are using `import`/`export` and *you are trying to run the files directly without compilation.*

The mindshift here is getting used to editing the files in one directory and running the tests in another.  Alternatively, some solutions offer "in'flight" compilation so this detail is essentially hidden and only the source files are used.

There are a few different approaches to doing this depending on specific needs. Here is one of the simplest approach I've found so far, using Babel for the compilation step:

- Install babel  `npm install babel --save-dev`
- Add babel commands in `package.json` scripts, for example:

  ```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "babel src/ --out-dir lib --presets=@babel/env; jest lib/*.test.js",
    "build": "babel src/ --out-dir lib --presets=@babel/env"
  },  // this was for jest but you can use mocha, etc as needed
      // Note that using preset this way eliminates the need for a specific .babel.config.json file
  ```

Now, if you run:

```
jest .
```

you get `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`, but if you run `npm t` you get

```
Successfully compiled 2 files with Babel.
 PASS  lib/app.test.js
  All tests
    ✓ Canary test (2ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
```

Going forward, just remember to:

- Edit files in `src/`
- Run tests in `lib/`